# Being slapped more than once at work

Tags: harassment

My coworker who is a black female, and I am a white male, constantly slaps me. The last incident took place as my boss an I walked in the door said she was startled and slapped me hard. She has done this on repeated occasions, and I have told her not to do that, but this time it left a welt. My supervisor asked if she heard us come in and she said she was concentrating on putting a plug in the wall.

She is in a management position as I am. She has been told before not to do that by other people in her area that have had the same problem. I am seriously close to going to HR about this, but I do not want to cause friction. I told my superior that the slapping is demeaning, embarrassing and uncalled for, but it keeps happening. I just do not like the physical violent action.

Comment: see also: [Copying questions that had a misfortune of being widely exposed in the hot list](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2445/168)

Comment: If this is real, then call the police.  No one should have to take being assaulted as part of their job.  If it were a male slapping a female, the bond hearing would be set by now.

Answer (score -1):

Oh my. Do you think her being a "Black Female" and you being a "White male" has anything, whatsoever, to do with it? Would you feel better if she were an Icelander? No. Maybe you should focus less on race, and more on standing up for yourself, looking her in the eye, and demanding that the abuse stop, or you will address it with HR.

Being that HR has this on file, they can write her up and if it happens again, she can be fired. HR does not NEED to divulge who the complaint is from.

HR needs to be real clear on how this is effecting you - its assault, and it's their job to provide a safe workplace. This is a threat to their business.

You're going to continue to get slapped if she can get away with it.

Comment: this reads more like a rant, see [answer]

Comment: And please do not answer questions that are closed (as duplicate in this case).